# Execute Express post route on arbitary button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I run an arbitary Express route from the client, on a button click?

I need to execute a `post` route when the user clicks a button. This button is not inside a form. (The button is created using jQuery during user interaction, if that's useful).

Here is the button handler:

```
$(document).on('click',"#gobutton",function (e){
     // EXECUTE POST ROUTE HERE, GO TO NEW PAGE.
}
```

I don't want to do this as a jQuery Ajax post, because it's untidy. The correct route already exists, it's just that the user is outside the normal workflow of the page.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you don't want to use an XHR (ajax)? This seems like its ideal use case unless your post route returns the new page you want to go to.

Comment: My understanding is that I need to include the URL. From a keeping-track-of-things point of view, it seems that the whole point of routes is that all that sort of code is stored there, in one place.

Comment: Also, on trying that option, I get this: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8000/go. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: Either make the button a `submit` element on a `<form action="/url" method="POST">`, or make the same call with AJAX. If you really need to access the page on one domain and send the post to another domain, use the [`cors`](https://npmjs.org/package/cors) middleware on the server